# Is it possible to pullAll on multiple matched results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following documents:

```
{
   _id: 1
   items: ['1a', '1b', '1c']
},
{
   _id: 2,
   items: ['2a', '2b', '2c']
}
```

Is it possible to pull items from these documents but only if all the items exist?

To explain:

I need to pull '1a', '1c' and '2b' elemnets from these documents, so I if issue the query like the following:

```
var updateObj = ['1a', '1c', '2b'];
db.collection.update({_id : {$in updateObj}}, {$pullAll: {items: updateObj}});
```

Than will return success and pull the items.

However if issue the following query:

```
var updateObj = ['1a', '1c', '2z'];
db.collection.update({_id : {$in updateObj}}, {$pullAll: {items: updateObj}});
```

Then I want the update to fail, because 2z does not exist in any of the documents.

Comment: Apologies for the length of the response. I understand that English is not your first language, but I saw the *use case* in this an thought it deserved a proper explanation, as to why the cases fail and how to test for the update conditions you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this took me a few moments to get my head around but I'm sure I understand now. Hold on because this is a lengthy explanation, and I hope I am not confusing you with the english.

As you are saying, given the arguments to [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) what you want to do is [$pullAll](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) the elements from the array field, **but only** when **all** of those elements where found. (There is a possible accepted edit to your question that may clear that up by now).

As it stands, you would be aware that your **second** case will of course *pull* the matching elements ('1a', '1c') from the matching document even though your '2z' element does not match any document in the collection. With what you want to achieve I think that last statement is the most important point.

The main problem with this condition, and hence why it does not work, is because you are matching elements that span over **different documents**.

Take your **first** case that you expect to match. The specified elements ('1a', '1c', '2b') matches both of the documents you give as a sample. This is because given the `$in` operator, both documents meet the condition, where the *first* has elements ('1a', '1c') and the *second* matches ('2b') as one of the elements.

Here your operation is simple (provided you use a `multi` update) where you have *matched* two documents, and the update portion is simple. So for the documents that match, we just want to pull the array elements out from the list provided. And this works just fine.

In your **second** case, we can see that '2z' is not going to be *seen* in **any** document in the collection. But as we are *spanning* documents and also with the usage of `$in`, we find that the **first** document is a match for the condition ('1a' and '1c' are present and match the $in). So what this means is that `$pullAll` with the arguments given is going to **act** on this document. And as you will be aware, `$pullAll` does not care if **all** the elements do not exist, it will just pull everything that matches the list given.

So here you can see the problem, is that we are over multiple documents and **one** of the documents (or more) is going to match these conditions, but you want to do something different.

So can you do this in your `update` form? Well, no. But we can take another approach. What we want to do is test if **all** the elements *match* within documents in the collection. So for this we need to **analyse** first before we make the decision to update.

Take care, this is a little contrived. But bear with me:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Look for "just what we are expecting to match"
    {$match: {items: {$in: ['1a','1c', '2z']}} },

    // Unwind the array for matching
    {$unwind: "$items"},

    // Pool this back into "one document"
    {$group: { _id: null, items: {$addToSet: "$items"}}}

    // Now ask the question again "Do you match **all**?"
    {$match: {items: {$all: ['1a', '1c', '2z']}}}
])
```

So what this will do, (and better explained by looking through it in steps) is look through the documents that **may** match your initial *set* and group the *elements* all together as an actualt *set* across all documents. Then we *finally* ask the question, "*Are **all** of these things found within the collection?*"

The process above with '2z' in the elements will not return a result, but with '2b' it will. And so, with this **test** performed **before** you issue the update statement, you can achieve the result you want.

It's not a **fail** on update, but you can check for the *fail* **before** you even issue the update and meet the conditons you want.

Phew! Where's my glass of wine?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how you get good result for the first query because you don't have any IDs which match '1a' or '1c' or '2b'.

I think that your query should looks like this:
`db.collection.update({items: {$in: updateObj}}, {$pullAll: {items: updateObj}}, {multi: true});`

Comment: The first query will be success because '1a', '1c' and '2b' exists in the first and second documments respectively. What about your query I have one question: what happens if in some of the documents have no elements like in the second query?

Comment: I don't see at first and second documents fields _id equal to '1a' or '1c' or '2b'. I think you're confused `_id` field with `items` field in your question. Answer to your question: If some of the documents have no elements like in the second query, it will not match query in update function and will not be updated.

Comment: @Erik I get what you are asking, but to properly answer will take me a little while to type out. So if you can be patient ...

Comment: @DenisNikanorov as just said. Typing an answer, but you need to consider what $in is doing in this context. The question implies that **all** of the elements need to match documents within the collection in order to affect the update.

Comment: @Neil Lunn, if so both queries will not work.. Because there is no documents with field items contain all elements of ['1a', '1c', '2b'] or ['1a', '1c', '2z']... If you want to find documents which have field `items` contains ALL elements of `updateObj` array you should change query in my answer form '$in' to '$all'

Comment: @DenisNikanorov `$all` does not work that way. Check the documentation. There is another approach, it's just not atomic. (Well, technically this is not either)

Comment: @Neil Lunn OK. I think don't really understand your comment))

Comment: @DenisNikanorov my answer, **big read** may clear up what I was commenting about here. What I run through is matching the conditions over the **entire** collection. As was intended in the question. It's a good question actually.