# Why is it not possible to find documents with '$all' modifier?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following documents:

```
{
   _id: 1
   title: "oneItem"
},
{
   _id: 2,
   title: "twoItem"
}
```

When I try to find these documents by using the following command:

```
db.collection.documents.find({_id: {$in: [1, 2]}});
```

I get these two documents but when I try to find these documents by using the following query:

```
db.collection.documents.find({_id: {$all: [1, 2]}});
```

I get nothing. Can you explain what's the problem? Basically I need to find all documents with _id 1 and 2 and if none exist then fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning is actually quite simple in that [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) and [$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) have two completely different functions. The documentation links are there, but to explain:

Consider these documents:

```
{
   _id: 1,
   items: [ "a", "b" ]
},
{
   _id: 2,
   items: [ "a", "b", "c" ]
}
```

**$in** - provides a *list* of arguments that can possibly match the value in the field being tested. This would match as follows:

```
db.collection.find({ items: {$in: [ "a", "b", "c" ] }})

{
   _id: 1,
   items: [ "a", "b" ]
},
{
   _id: 2,
   items: [ "a", "b", "c" ]
}
```

**$all** - provides a list where the field being matched is expected to be an array and **all** of the listed elements are present in that array. E.g

```
db.collection.find({ items: {$all: [ "a", "b", "c" ] }})

{
   _id: 2,
   items: [ "a", "b", "c" ]
}
```

Hence why your query does not return a result, the field is not an array and does not contain **both** elements.

The MongoDB [operator reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/) is something you *should* really read through.

As your your statement, ["I need to find all documents with _id 1 and 2 and if someone from them does not exists then fail."], matching various criteria is *easy* as you see in the usage of **$in**. Your problem is you want a **whole set** to match or otherwise return nothing ("fail"). This I have already explained to you an some length in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21881817/2313887), but to re-iterate:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match on what you want to find
    {$match: { list: {$in: [1,2]} }},

    // Add the found results to a distinct *set*
    {$group: { _id: null, list: {$addToSet: "$_id"} }},

    // Only return when *all* the expected items are in the *set*
    {$match: { list: {$all: [1,2]} }}
])
```

So after that manipulation, this will only return a result if **all** of the items where found. That is how we use **$all** to match in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the response but how could I get all documents with _id 1 and 2 or fail if one of them does not exists?

Comment: @Erik I expanded on the usage. That should explain better. I also explained your comment (not your question here) in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/a/21881817/2313887